# How to convert a centralized algorithm to a distributed algorithm?

Tags: distributed-systems

Is there any algorithm or procedure to convert a centralized algorithm to a distributed algorithm? Is there any theoretical result or relevant complexity analysis?

Comment: How did you go about your search for such algorithms, what did it result up to now? It would seem a waste of energy to produce references you already know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  If you have a distributed system with N machines, you can always run the centralized algorithm on machine 1 and let machines 2..N sit idle.

If you're asking whether all sequential algorithms can be parallelized, that's an open question, but it's believed that the answer is no: see the [NC complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29).  As Wikipedia states,

> there are probably some tractable problems that are "inherently sequential" and cannot significantly be sped up by using parallelism.

P-complete problems are good candidates for problems that are likely not amenable to speedup by parallelism.

If you're asking whether all algorithms can be made reliable in a distributed system, that is a subtle question that depends on what kinds of failures you are considering.  You might look into [consensus protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)), [state machine replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine_replication), and the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the complexity class.  It says  

 "parallel computations can be simulated by polynomial-time sequential ones"

Is there any generalized procedure to convert the parallel algorithm into a sequential one?  I am assuming here that the given algorithm is already polynomial time in centralized version.

Comment: @RupokSaha,  simulate running them in parallel on a sequential interpreter.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science).